# c++ template return type of operator[]

Tags: c++

Considering a class, Foo, I want to define an operator[] overload that is actually a template, where the return type is templated:

```
class Foo
{
    template<typename T> T operator[](size_t i)
    {
        return *(reinterpret_cast<T *>(get some pointer));
    }
}
```

This works and compiles, but I can't figure out how to use it. I don't know where to specify the type when invoking it. To provide a reference example, suppose I replace operator[] with the function name at:

```
class Foo
{
    template<typename T> T at(size_t i)
    {
        return *(reinterpret_cast<T *>(get some pointer));
    }
}
```

Then I can do something like:

```
Foo foo;

int myFooInt = foo.at<int>(32); // gets an int at position 32
```

This compiles and given an actual implementation of some kind of positioned memory provided by "get some pointer", it returns the correct value. (Note, I'm not providing any information about what "position" means, and it really doesn't matter to my question, in this case.)

But I can't figure out how/where to specify the type when using [].

By the way, the following does work:

```
int myFooInt = foo.operator[]<int>(32);
```

but something like this doesn't compile:

```
int myFooInt = foo[32]<int>;
```

nor does this:

```
int myFooInt = foo<int>[32];
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: `foo.operator[]<int>` is the only way to use a template like this. There is no other alternative.

Comment: Have you considered an array of [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/any.html)?  Your `Foo` class seems to be doing `std::any` already does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case, the index is actually a char index, and only after computing the offset on that basis is the type-casting to the return type done. (i.e., Get the int (or float, or whatever) that's stored i bytes into my generic buffer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to provide explicit template arguments for operator syntax, your foo.at(ndx) is the usual answer if you want that sort of thing.